# Find the HTTP status code of an image at `onload` event

Tags: javascript

Suppose the following code:

```
var img = new Image(1, 1);
img.onload = function() {
    console.log(arguments);
};
img.src = 'some.place.com/some/image.jpg';
```

When the image will load, it will print `arguments`, which contains an `Event` object, with information about the request event, but I can't find anywhere the status code.

The firing of the `onload` event doesn't distinguish between a direct successful request or a successful anything else like a redirect.

I need to distinguish in my code if this request was direct or a redirect, but I can't find out how without the HTTP status code. Is there somewhere this information available?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is that it is not possible, as researches show.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the HTTP status of request made by an image element in JavaScript, you'd need to use AJAX as a loader in order to access information like this.

Alternately, you can use `img.complete`:

> **HTMLImageElement.complete** 
>   Returns a Boolean that is true if the browser has fetched the image, and it is in a supported image type that was decoded without
>   errors.[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement)

Comment: The problem with AJAX requests is that they don't work cross-domain unless the other domain sends CORS headers. I need to check it against an image not in my domain.